# Corrupt data in zip prevents it from being extracted after download

Tags: python, urllib2, python-zipfile

I´ve set up a server with a zip file named bk_data.zip and want to download and extract the content. The zip file is downloaded, but the data is corrupt and can´t be extracted. I´ve read about the zipfile objects ([docs.python.org/2.7/library/zipfile.html)](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/zipfile.html)  and tried different mode parameters, but without succes. Help is appreciated. This is my code:

```
import urllib2
import zipfile

my_download_url = "http://xx.xxx.xx.x/bk_data.zip"
request = urllib2.urlopen(my_download_url)

output = open("C:/that/very/long/path/bk_data.zip", "w")
output.write(request.read())
output.close()

with zipfile.ZipFile("C:/that/very/long/path/bk_data.zip', "r") as z:
    z.extractall("C:/that/very/long/path/")
```

Comment: try changing `"w"` and `"r"` to `"wb"` and `"rb"` to open the files in binary mode

Comment: That worked maxymoo. Thank you. Please add is as your answer.

Comment: no worries, glad it worked

Comment: I really struggled with this, and yet so simple. Python is still challenging, but fun for me :-)

Comment: yeah there's a few little quirks like this one that take quite a while to get used to ... another one to watch out for is `latin-1` vs `utf-8` encoding for strings if you're working on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `"w"` and `"r"` to `"wb"` and `"rb"` to open the files in binary mode.

Comment: However, if I try 'rb' I get the error message: RuntimeError: ZipFile() requires mode "r", "w", or "a"